# How to process JSON coming from a android in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, rest, express

**How to process JSON coming from a android in nodejs**

I am building rest APIs in node using express. my API's are used by web client as well as from Android. From android  data come in this form

```
"{\"info\":\"abc\"}"
```

and from react app its come in this form

```
{ info:"abc"}
```

so what is the solution of it i have search it but don't find any thing. and tell me what is the better way of exchanging data in rest API's.

what i have tried.

when i use JSON.parse it work fine with android but it through error

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
```

If i send data from react app using JSON.stringify it give this error

```
Cannot convert object to primitive value
```

Comment: For android use `JSON.parse("{\"info\":\"abc\"}")`

Comment: Yes i have tried it. work fine then with andriod. but for my react app it through error

Comment: Since you get different formats from different sources, it makes sense to just use an if clause or ternary or something. `if ( android ) data = JSON.parse(???) else if (react) data = ???;`

Comment: Depending on how good your perfomance needs to be, you could even use `let jsonValue; try { jsonValue = JSON.parse(data) } catch (err) { jsonValue = data}` or even simpler/better performing: `jsonValue = typeof data === 'string' ? JSON.parse(data) : data`

Answer (score 2):

You're receiving a JSON string, just use [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse), like so:

```
const object = JSON.parse(your_JSON_string)
```

EDIT: since you've altered the question afterwards, if you're getting a

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

it (probably) means that you've already got an object, no need to call `JSON.parse()` upon it.

Regarding the error that you're getting when you're trying to send data from the React app, you need to set the `content-type` header in your request to a proper content type.

My advice is to try and get a quick type check before you run any parsing on it, something along the lines of:

```
function getOrParseObject(your_received_object){
    if(typeof(your_received_object) === 'string') {
        // It's a string, should be parsed, so:
        return JSON.parse(your_received_object)
    } else if (typeof(your_received_object) === 'object'){
       // It's already an object, no need to parse it
       return your_received_object
    }
}
```

Comment: if it don't use JSON.parse it through me an error for andriod. but  it work for react and vice versa.

Comment: @osama Edited again